# known dictionary structure, but very nested - alternative to ugly code

Tags: python, dictionary, plist

Using `plistlib` to load a plist file in Python, I have a data structure to work with wherein a given path to a key-value pair should never fail, so it's acceptable IMO to hard-code the path without `.get()` and other tricks -- however, it is a long and ugly path. The plist is full of dicts in arrays in dicts, so it ends up looking like this:

```
def input_user_data(plist, user_text):
    new_text = clean_user_data(user_data)
    plist['template_data_array'][0]['template_section']['section_fields_data'][0]['disclaimer_text'] = new_text  #do not like
```

Apart from being way past the 79 character limit, it just looks lugubrious and sophomoric. However it seems equally silly to step through it like this:

```
#....
one = plist['template_data_array']
two = one[0]['template_section']['section_fields_data']
two[0]['disclaimer_text'] = new_text
```

...because I don't really *need* all those assignments, I'm just looking to sanitize the user text and toss it into the predefined section of a plist.

When dealing with a nested path that will always exist but is just tedious to access (and may indeed need to be found again by other methods), is there a shorter technique to employ, or do I just grin and bear the lousy nested structure that I have no control over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see a lot of duplicated or boilerplate code, this is often a hint that you can refactor the repetitive operations into a function. Writing `get_node` and `set_node` helper functions not only makes the code that sets the values simpler, it allows you to easily define the paths as constants, which you can put all in one place in your code for easier maintenance.

```
def get_node(container, path):
    for node in path:
        container = container[node]
    return container

def set_node(container, path, value):
    container = get_node(container, path[:-1])
    container[path[-1]] = value

DISCLAIMER_PATH = ("template_data_array", 0, "template_section", "section_fields_data", 
                   0, "disclaimer_text")

set_node(plist, DISCLAIMER_PATH, new_text)
```

Potentially, you could subclass `plist`'s class to have these as methods, or even to override `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`, which would be convenient.

Comment: Not sure why `get_node` didn't naturally occur to me, that's really slick. +1